# glReadPixels returning different data types in Python

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I am using working with OpenGL via Python 3.6 / PyOpenGL 3.1.0 in Ubuntu on two different machines with the same configuration (unless there is something I am missing).

I'm running the same script on both machines.

Code goes like that:

```
    pixels = glReadPixels(0, 0, 640, 640, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT)
    print(pixels)
```

On one machine the `print` displays:

```
<OpenGL.arrays.ctypesarrays.c_float_Array_640_Array_640_Array_3 object at 0x7fcd1e681158>
```

whereas on the other I get an array of floats, as expected:

```
[[[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  ...
```

What do you think about this? Thank you.

Comment: Could be the same, try `print(type(pixels))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Joe's advice, I tried `print(type(pixels))` and found:

`<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` on the machine that printed nice-looking matrices

vs

`<OpenGL.arrays.ctypesarrays. ...>` on the other one.

It turned out that the second machine missed `numpy`. After installing `numpy`, the result was identical to that obtained on the first machine.

This had been especially annoying since the script second machine crashed when trying to serialize the data with `pickle`.

Leaving this answer here in the hope that others might find it useful.